# Is there a way to decompile an apk built through Expo and open the resulting project in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native, expo

I've been building some apps in react native using expo and wanted to see how the code looks in java in Android studio. I'm having trouble using decompiler(I've tried jadx, decompileandroid.com, and CFR). When I open the folder in android studio I can't find any source files other than classes named a,b,c,etc that have maybe 10 lines of code. I can't even find the strings that were in my app.

Does expo build the apk with proguard enabled? If so, is there a way to disable it? I have the react native source, I just want to see the java analogue. Is this a problem solely from using expo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use a project you created using `"expo"` in your `Android studio`, you need to separate `expo.`

To separate, run `'expo eject'`. This will result in an `android` file and an `iOS` file.

this is [link](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/expokit/eject/) about `expo eject`

ExpoKit is an Objective-C and Java library that allows you to use the Expo platform and your existing Expo project as part of a larger standard native project -- one that you would normally create using Xcode, Android Studio, or react-native init.

You can use the new Android file to run the Android studio.